# Appium + Selenium : FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am using appium studio from where i got the code and  i have copied from it in Eclipse.I have added All maven dependencies even though it is throwing error of **FAILED configuration.** Does anybody help me with this?
Note: I am here using Real device ios and my platform is mac . java version "11.0.2"

```java
package iostestdemo;

import io.appium.java_client.remote.IOSMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class secondTest {
    private String reportDirectory = "reports";
    private String reportFormat = "xml";
    private String testName = "Untitled";
    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = null;

    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
        dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
        dc.setCapability("testName", testName);
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "afb65172e9b47b01482d912dede58515819748a3");
        dc.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID, "com.novo.ios.dev");
        driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
        driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUntitled() {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "(//*[@text='Novo - Dev']/*/*[@class='UIAView' and ./*[@class='UIAView' and ./*[@class='UIAView']] and ./parent::*[@class='UIAWindow']])[2]"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Email']")).sendKeys("ababddvdvd");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("vvv");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();
    }
}
```

Error that i am facing:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:86)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:96)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:92)
    at iostestdemo.secondTest.setUp(secondTest.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 41 more

SKIPPED: testUntitled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:86)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:96)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:92)
    at iostestdemo.secondTest.setUp(secondTest.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 41 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Maven Dependency :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.iostestdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>iostestdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: check you classpath in Eclipse. It looks like selenium server jar is missing on your classpath

Comment: I have put jar in maven repo. selenium-server -> version- 3.141.59 . Please check the last dependency

Comment: I meant the build path. ( right click on the source folder and click configure build path) make sure this jar is available on the libraries org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

Comment: it is there. please check screenshot  : http://prntscr.com/ocml25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suffering from a form of [JAR Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

Looking into [dependencies for Appium Java Client 7.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.1.0) it already depends on [Selenium 4.0.0-alpha-1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-1)

You're getting errors due to the conflict between dependencies you're declare in your [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file and [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) of the Appium Java Client

You basically need only Appium Java Client in order to be able to run Appium-based tests, you don't need to add Selenium libraries, the relevant versions will be automatically resolved:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

More information including example projects: [Appium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java)

Comment: If I only keep Java Client dependency then `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities` can't be resolved.

Comment: We still need Selenium dependences in order to use DesiredCapabilities. change java-client version to 7.0.0 will solve problem

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too and it was hard for me to solve. I think that version of appium (7.1.0) and selenium (3.141.59) dependency is not supported for each other. I changed the version of that like following and it solved for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```